# how do i count number of admins in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

when i perform the following aggregate.my expectation is to get roles count for dashboard as expected in my  output below but what i am getting is 0 for admin,extension,seeder values respectively. what do you think is my mistake?

model

```
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    roles: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Role"
      }
    ],
  
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
```

This is the aggregate i am working on...
**controller**

```
exports.userRoleCount = (rep,res,next) =>{
    
  User.aggregate([
  {$project: {
    admin: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$roles", "['admin']"]}, 1, 0]},
    seeder: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$roles", "seeder"]}, 1, 0]},
    extension: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$roles", "extension"]}, 1, 0]},
  }},
  {$group: { _id: null, admin: {$sum: "admin"},
                        seeder: {$sum: "$seeder"},
                        extension: {$sum: "$extension"},
                        total: {$sum: 1},
  }},
], (error,data)=>{
  if (error){
    return next(error);
  } else {
    res.json(data);
  }

}
)
```

This is the output i get
**output**

```
{
        "_id": null,
        "admin": 0,
        "seeder": 0,
        "extension": 0,
        "total": 9
    }
```

My expectation was this.....

```
{
        "_id": null,
        "admin": 3,
        "seeder": 4,
        "extension": 2,
        "total": 9
    }
```

This is my roles array...
db.ROLES = ["user", "admin", "extension", "seeder"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code fragment as follow and it worked!!

```
 exports.userRoleCount = (rep,res,next) =>{

      User.aggregate([
      {
       "$project": {
          "_id": 1,
          "roles": 1
      }
    },

 {
    "$unwind": "$roles"
      },

      {
       "$group": {
        "_id": '$roles',
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
  
         }

 
          },
              {"$sort": {"_id": -1}},
              {"$limit": 5}
                      ], (error,data)=>{
                if (error){
               return next(error);
                   } else {
                 res.json(data);
               // console.log(data[1].count);
                      }
   
                   }
                   )
   


                   }
```

And the output looks like as follow

```
           { 
               {

             _id:1     // this id is for role admin
             count: 2

           },

           
           {

             _id:2     // this id is for role extension
             count: 5

           }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hi, 
    
      {$unwind : "$roles"},
      {$group: { _id: null, 
          admin: {$sum: {$eq : ["roles": "admin"]}},
  seeder: {$sum: {$eq : ["roles": "seeder"]}},
                          
                            total: {$sum: 1},
      }},
```

Comment: hi Rohit, i have an error  admin: {$sum: {$eq : ["roles": "admin"]}},
                                                                                    ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'  besides i have got the same results after replacing ':' by ',' and possible please specify the place where i can put you code fragment in my code above. thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Hi, sorry use comma (,) in place of :

and just replace your query with this aggregate query

Comment: @ Rohit K Choudhary, what i have got it  just an null set... i couldn't get what i miss...